# app works fine on emulator but app can't be installed on mobile via apk package

Tags: android, gradle

I wrote an application for android 5.1.1 using android studio 3.6 canary 3.
Mobile is samsung xcover 3 (sm-g388f) with 5.1.1 android stock rom api22

Running on emulator 5.1.1  api 22 doesnt show any errors in logcat just 
E/libprocessgroup: failed to make and chown /acct/uid_10058: Read-only file system

App is completed and its fully working on emulator.

Building debug build type apk.
I got space on phone.
Doesn't have dev play store account, dont have cash for it now.
I am zipping apk to zip, send over gmail to phone, download unzip and install.

I tried various compile, buildtools versions.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.pippboy"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true


            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            debuggable = true
        }
        debug {
            minifyEnabled  true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android:flexbox:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
}
```

Apk got 1mb. This is my first app. I just want to install on mobile via apk package downloaded from some host.

Answer (score 0):

On the device have you set the Security option to allow APKs to be installed from untrusted (ie, not the Google Play Store) sources?  You'll need to allow that first.  You shouldn't have to, but you might also want to allow for USB debugging on the device.

Comment: Yes, yes, i done everything on phone. Allowed unsigned,untrusted apps and debugging via usb.

Comment: OK, so, how far do you get?  Are you trying to download the .zip or the .apk? Are you able to download the .apk file to Downloads?  Are you able to install it, but it fails to run?  If yes to the latter, you could try plugging the device into Android Studio and monitor the logs when you try to run your App.

Comment: i got apk at my phone. instalation starts... ...  ..  installing . . .. . . . . instaling . .. . . . . "App cannot be installed" comunicate

Comment: when i use my phone to "debug" and install app via usb via android studio apk is installed on phone and its working

Comment: Could be where it is trying to install the app.  Go to Settings/Storage and tap on Preferred Install Location.  If the option of SD Card is checked, uncheck it.  Also, choose the option to let the system decide on the location.

Comment: i dont have SD card in phone or in stock

Comment: i made some more space from 400mb to 800mb and still cant install this shit

Comment: Did you go to Settings/Storage anyway to see what is selected?

Comment: I think u cant select this option when sd card is not attached. I went through all settings and i cant select or find preferred install location.

Comment: App got installed on phone after spamming a lot install attempt. Sometimes install at   1 try sometimes at 8.